# Observable keyup event only when user enter key

Tags: angular, observable

I have below code

```
 Observable.fromEvent(this.inputref.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .map((evt: any) => evt.target.value)
      .filter(res => {
        if (res.length > 1) {
          return true;
        } else {
        }
      }).debounceTime(1000)
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((text: string) => this.callmethod(text.trim()));
  }
```

The above code is working fine, but issue is it also gets fired when input is filled by coding like

```
this.inputref.nativeElement.value = "value"
```

or when binbding varible change like below

```
<input type="text" #inputref value="{{input_val}}" />

this.input_val = "text value"
```

How to make it fire only when user press key not when input by logic.

Thanks

Comment: you can use `(keyup)="methodhere()"` inside input tag.

Comment: I cannot change that event, I need to have that, i want only to restrict event not to file when data populate through code

Comment: you can have boolean for Observable.fromEvent when you populate then make it false and when you are not then make it true with if

Comment: But once I made it false while populating then when ill made it false, bcz then after if user type, i need to know how value is being inserting there by code or by user

Comment: Or might be i need to align with onfocus as well

Comment: use keyup.enter

Comment: Try **[this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-angular4-wh3qdw?file=app/app.component.ts)** I'm not able to replicate the issue that you're mentioning.

Comment: try: Observable.fromEvent(this.inputref.nativeElement, 'keyup.enter')

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

.html file:

```
<input type="text" [formControl]="testControl" (input)="testMethod()">
```

In .ts file:

Create Form control:

```
 testControl: FormControl = new FormControl('');
```

create input change method:

```
testMethod(){
    console.log('Test control Change event', this.testControl.value);
}
```

Following code for set the value from code side:

```
this.testControl.setValue('Hello');
```